# Как массово установить внешний ключ Null? EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

#### Есть такие модели

```
public class Product // Товар
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class ProductCategory // Категория товаров
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Product> Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();
}
```

Мне нужно массово изменить у товаров категорию `null`, в которых `CategoryId = 1`

#### Я пытаюсь сделать так

```
await _context.Products.Where(w => w.Id == 1)
            .ExecuteUpdateAsync(s=>s.SetProperty(u=>u.Category, u=>u.Category = null));
```

Но получаю ошибку

```
An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator
```

Как мне решить эту задачу?

Comment: `SetProperty(u=>u.Category, null)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Сам нашёл решение

В модели сделал `CategiryId` необязательным, добавив `int?`

```
public class Product // Товар
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? CategoryId { get; set; }

    public ProductCategory Category { get; set; }
}
```

Потом в контроллере делаю так:

```
await _context.Products.Where(w => w.Id == 1)
.ExecuteUpdateAsync(s=>s.SetProperty(u=> u.CategoryId, u=> null));
```